# cakephp avoid logged in users to access other user's account

Tags: cakephp, save, authentication

I'm developing a web with CakePHP 1.3.7. Everything is going fine and I love it, but I just came accross a problem (probably because of my lack of knowledge) that I can't figure out how to fix.

This is my problem:

In the website, there's the typical 'manage my account' area, where users can only access when they're logged in. In this area, there's a link that calls to an action in the same 'users' controller called 'edit_items'. So when a user goes to **edit_items**, the action receives as a parameter the user's **id** (something like domain.com/users/edit_items/45, where 45 is the user's id), and shows the information in a form. The problem comes if I go directly to the address bar of the browser and change that 45 for any other user's Id, then the information of that other user is also shown, even if that user is not logged in. This is obviously a big security issue.

I've been trying to avoid passing the user's id as a parameter and getting it from the Auth component (which I'm using) with **$this->Auth->User('id')**. For whatever reason, I can read the logged user's info into the form fine, but when I try to save the changes on the form, I get an error as if the **save** action had failed, and I have no clue why.

Is there any other way to avoid my problem? Or to figure out why the **save** is returning an error?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

SO the problem comes from the validation, here's the deal: when the user fills out the form to create a new item, there are certain fields, some of them with validation rules applied. However, when the user goes back to edit the item, not all the fields are editable, only some. Is it possible that, since some fields that required validation when creating the item are not available when editing, that causes the error? How can avoid that? Can I change the validation rules only for the **edit** action?

Example of what's happening: when creating an item,one of the fields is **item_name**, which has some validation applied to it. When editing the item, its name can not be changed, so it's not shown in the edit form. I believe this what may be causing the error, maybe because the **item_name** is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are turned on the right direction - passing user_id on the url is a bad idea when the users need to edit their own details.

You can use following: when saving your form before the actual save you can pass the user_id to the posted data. Something like this:

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
   $this->data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
   ... //Some extra stuff
   if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
      ... //success
   } else {
      ... //error
   }
}
```

This way the logged user will override it's own record always. Check if you have some validation rules in your model which give you this error.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is in the validation, you're right, I need to figure out why though

Comment: Solved it! :) Just add `unset($this->User->validate['field']);` before the 'save' function for all the fields you don't want to validate